# Android Side Navigation - Use Activity or Fragment to switch between classes

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I am using a side navigation (https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation) for my app. I am new to `Android`, so I am not exactly sure the best way of switching between my `classes` when a user taps one of the side navigation items.

I have read that I should use `Fragements` for this, does this mean use an `ActivityFragement`? Is this the best way to switch between classes, or should I switch between activities?

Just wanting to do it the correct way and make sure not to load up the class again if a user has already visited it.

```
@Override
public void onSideNavigationItemClick(int itemId) {
    switch (itemId) {
        case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item1:
            invokeActivity(getString(R.string.sideTitleNews), itemId);
            break;

        case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item2:
            invokeActivity(getString(R.string.sideTitlePhotos), itemId);
            break;


        default:
            return;
    }

}


private void invokeActivity(String title, int itemId) {

    Fragment fragment;
    Intent intent;
    switch (itemId) {
    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item1:
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        break;

    case R.id.side_navigation_menu_item2:
        intent = new Intent(this, PUCPhotosActivity.class);
        break;

        default:
            return;
    }

    // Load fragement or Activity?

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest studying the fragments UI tutorial as jump point - I think this link has what you need ... or at least it's somewhere right from that dev page. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: follow up ... you have to think in two device classes - small phones or tablets. Frags can be set up pretty easily to deal with both.

Comment: am using this same library & want to change fragment page while selecting the menu items.can u post the answer for this question?.. i am not able to change this page with same state like fb.